# run an external script and print the output in real-time in a text widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to run an external script (demo_print.py) and print the output in real-time in a text widget.

I got error:

What's my mistake and how to reach my goal ? You can suggest more simple solution if you have.

```py
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/python3/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/bin/python3/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "example_gui.py", line 37, in test
textbox.insert(tk.END, msg + "\n")
File "example_gui.py", line 20, in write
self.widget.insert('end', textbox)
File "/usr/bin/python3/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3272, in insert
self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)
_tkinter.TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
```

I want to run an external script (demo_print.py) and print the output in real-time in a text widget.

**example_gui.py**

```py
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
import threading
import sys
from functools import partial


# ### classes ####

class Redirect:

    def __init__(self, widget, autoscroll=True):
        self.widget = widget
        self.autoscroll = autoscroll

    def write(self, textbox):
        self.widget.insert('end', textbox)
        if self.autoscroll:
            self.widget.see('end')  # autoscroll

    def flush(self):
        pass


def run(textbox=None):
    threading.Thread(target=test, args=[textbox]).start()


def test(textbox=None):
    p = subprocess.Popen("demo_print.py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, text=True)
    while p.poll() is None:
        msg = p.stdout.readline().strip()  # read a line from the process output
        if msg:
            textbox.insert(tk.END, msg + "\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fenster = tk.Tk()
    fenster.title("My Program")
    textbox = tk.Text(fenster)
    textbox.grid()
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(fenster, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
    scrollbar.grid()

    textbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.config(command=textbox.yview)

    start_button = tk.Button(fenster, text="Start", command=partial(run, textbox))
    start_button.grid()

    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = Redirect(textbox)

    fenster.mainloop()
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

**demo_print.py**

```py
import time
for i in range(10):
    print(f"print {i}")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: The exception shows that `print(msg)` is called inside `test()`, but the posted code does not have this line.  It is better to post  the real [mre].

Comment: For your case, you don't need the `Redirect` class at all.

Comment: I fixed the error output. Can you write me how to fix it ? @acw1668

Comment: Is `demo_print.py` executable? What is the [*shebang*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in the file? As I said in my past comment, you don't need the `Redirect` class at all.

Comment: Removed Redirect but I get the same error @acw1668 What's shebug ? I ran from unix and windows

Comment: Read the provided link on shebang in my last comment.

Comment: it's python 3.7.4 #!/usr/bin/python3/3.7.4/bin/python3 @acw1168

Answer (score 0):

Okay so first of all make sure demo_print.py is in the same space as your main.py not in a folder or anything then you can just do this:

```
from demo_print import *
print(whatever u named your output variable in demo_print)
```

From the looks of it you know how to do the rest.

Comment: The demo_print,py is ok and in the same directory .  I didn't understand your answer @Toiletman

Answer (score 0):

Since you execute `"demo_print.py"` directly, so it must be *executable* and has correct *shebang* (for example, `#!/usr/bin/python -u`) in the file.

However, I would suggest to execute the file using Python executable instead. Also the `Redirect` class is not necessary for your case.

Below is the modified code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
import threading
import sys
from functools import partial


def run(textbox=None):
    threading.Thread(target=test, args=[textbox]).start()


def test(textbox=None):
    # using the Python executable to run demo_print.py
    p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "-u", "demo_print.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, text=True)
    while p.poll() is None:
        msg = p.stdout.readline().strip()  # read a line from the process output
        if msg:
            textbox.insert(tk.END, msg + "\n")
            textbox.see(tk.END)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fenster = tk.Tk()
    fenster.title("My Program")
    textbox = tk.Text(fenster)
    textbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(fenster, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
    scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

    textbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.config(command=textbox.yview)

    start_button = tk.Button(fenster, text="Start", command=partial(run, textbox))
    start_button.grid()

    fenster.mainloop()
```

Comment: But I still got the error that I wrote in the beginning.  @acw1668

Comment: @Alex It works fine in my Windows running Python 3.8.14.

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't work from linux/unix ? @acw1668

Comment: @Alex It works fine in my Debian 11 running Python 3.9.2.

Comment: Thread is needed ? How can I do it without thread ? @acw1668

Comment: Using thread is recommended as there is while loop inside `test()`.

Comment: Can you explain me the meaning of Popen arguments ? For example: why do we need text and bufsize ? I can't understand it from python doc. @acw1668

Comment: @Alex You should ask yourself because those options are copied from your code.

Comment: I copied from another place. I'm trying to understand it. @acw1668

Comment: Can you explain why we need '-u' ? If I remove '-u' then it doesn't work @acw1668

Comment: You can get the description by running `python -h`:  "-u : force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered".

Comment: What does it mean ? it's not blocking. Can you explain me by example ? I want to understand it. @acw1668

Comment: The subprocess.Popen ,in your example, contains '-u' but how would it change if I run a csh script or exec file instead of python script ? @acw1668

Comment: You should look into the manual page of `csh` using command `man csh` in a console since your platform is Linux like OS.

Comment: I didn't find the same description. Can you point me to the correct flag ? @acw1668